# Iterate through elements generated with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('factory', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.users =[
        {name: 'jimbo', info: ''},
        {name: 'bobby', info: ''}
    ];

    $scope.addAllInfos = function(){

    };
});
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="factory">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        Name: <input value="{{user.name}}"/><br>
        Tell me sth: <input/><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="addAllInfos()">add all infos</button>

</body>
```

When clicking on "Add all infos" i want to iterate through all my users that i have generated by using ng-repeat and save the input of every "Tell me sth" input in the info-variable of the object.
How can I do so using Angular?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TipNo1/xsakgy6b/)

Comment: this is a classic case of not "thinking in angular".  Angular does not need a function to be executed to perform this, the two way binding does this for you without needing to perform any other logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bind every repeated input to `user.info` using `ngModel` directive:

```html
Tell me sth: <input type="text" ng-model="user.info" />
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/xsakgy6b/2/

Note, that in this case `addAllInfos` function may become redundant as two-way data binding automatically populates `user` objects for you.

Comment: awesome that really helped me. Can you also give me a tip regarding deleting the user in the context? So when every div has a delete button, how can i implement with angular to delete the right object from the array?

Comment: You will need to use [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove item from `$scope.users` array. Here is a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/xsakgy6b/4/

Comment: wow thank you, okay. what are you exactly invoking by using $index? Is this an angular specific command?

Comment: `ngRepeat` provides some useful variables inside the loop, one of them is current iteration `$index`. You need it if you want to remove item from array.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the ng-model attribute. You should use ng-model on your input fields as well, instead of putting the value into the value attribute. This will allow you to take full control of two-way binding in Angular.

Then you would not really need the addAllInfos function, Angular will keep track of the values and properties of each object in your repeater. The code would look like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/><br>
    Tell me sth: <input type="text" ng-model="user.info"/><br><br><br>
</div>
```

[Here's my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsakgy6b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is your addAllInfos() function.

You do not have your addAllInfos() function available to the view / html. You need to expose the function, either through $scope, or returned via the controller class.

You can do that like so:
$scope.addAllInfos = function() { // code here };

This will allow you to call a function from the ng-click event on your  .